# HTML/CSS: Content passing through footer when position is absolute

Tags: html, css, footer, responsiveness

I am trying to create a website with a responsive design, however I can only put so much content onto the web page until it passes and goes under the footer. I've been trying to put a set of images in a gallery format, and this problem is most discernible when I make the window smaller and the images begin stacking on top of each. This causes the images to pass through the footer instead of pushing it down if the footer was always stuck to the very bottom. I have been looking for solutions and been trying to set the position to relative, absolute, fixed and everything relating to padding and margins, but nothing seems to change. Apologies for the messy code.

PS: How can I get the footer to be malleable as in it being able to be pushed down when an indefinite amount of content is being added?

HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jof0hzhc/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="app">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>ResponsiveNav</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

</head>
<body class="bg2">
    <div class="wrapper">
            <header>

                  <nav>

                        <div class="menu-icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="logo">
                              ResponsiveNav
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu">
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> <!--Classifying the button as "activepage" will allow the button to be red when the user is on the page.-->
                                    <li><a href="apps.html" class="activepage">Current page</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                  </nav>

            </header>

            <section class="content">
            <p class="apphead">Heading</p>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                <div class="container2">
                <p class="apptext">Sub-heading</p>
                    <div class="games">

                        <img src="images/1.png">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/4.jpg">
                        <img src="images/5.jpg">
                        <img src="images/6.jpg">
                    </div>

                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                </div>


            </section>




      </div>


<footer>
<p class="foot">
        Footer text. <br>
        __________________________________________________________________________________________________ <br> <br>

        <a href="about.html" class="inquiry">About us </a> 

        |

        <a href="contact.html" class="inquiry">Contact us</a> <br>

        __________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
        <section>
            <p class="foot">Social Media</p>
                <span class="social">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mail.png" alt="Mail" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                </span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>All rights reserved<br></h3>
        </section>
</p>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 98%;
      background-color: black;
      min-height: 100%;
}

body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif; /*Keep this font or hamburger disappears*/
      font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
      width: 98%;
      height: 13vh;

}

li>a{display:;}
li>a:hover, /*li hover makes the area around the list of text have a block of color around it when you hover over the text*/
li>a:focus{color:red;text-decoration:underline;} /*li focus is when you select the element, the element gets into a focus*/


footer { /*How do I even make the footer always stick at the very bottom no wonder the dimensions of the browser?*/
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
    border-width: 10px;
    color: white;


}


p {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

a { /*General styling for links to other pages or websites*/
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
}

h2 { /*Styling for site title*/
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: courier;
}

h3 {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    color: white;
}




.content { /*the main container that consists of most of the existing content*/
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


}

.logo {
      line-height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      margin: 16px 46px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}


nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
      z-index: 1; /*Allows for the navigation bar to stack on top of content and not appear as it overlaps*/
}

nav ul {
      line-height: 60px;
      list-style: none;
      background: black;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding-right: 40px;
      transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
      background: orange;
      opacity: 10;
}

nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
      line-height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: orange;
      display: none;
}

.activepage { 
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.welcome {
    font-family: courier;
}

.inquiry {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
}


.container2 {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 97.8%;
    height: 1000px;
    z-index: 0;
    position:absolute;

}

p.heading {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;
}

.foot {
    color: white;

}

.bg2 {
    background-image:url("hex.jpg");
    height: 550px;
    width: 102%;


}

.apphead {
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: courier;
}

.apptext {
    color:white;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;

}

.games {
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    border:solid white; 
}

.games img {
    width: 640px;
    height:250px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 1s;

}

.games img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.item img{
    display:block;
}


@media(max-width: 786px) {

      .logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 16px;
      }

      nav ul {
            max-height: 0px;
            background: #000;
      }

      nav.black ul {
            background: #000;
      }

      .showing {
            max-height: 34em;
      }

      nav ul li {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 24px;
            text-align: center;
      }

      .menu-icon {
            display: block;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem if you add `overflow: hidden` to `container2` class.

Comment: Thanks that helped fix the footer being unable to stick to the bottom but my images still go under the footer. Is there a way that I can make the contents push the footer downwards indefinitely if I were to keep adding more content?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove position: absolute on mobile/tablet devices. Also, you need to remove height. It's not good to use fix height for sections.